# check if an email contains regex expresions

Tags: java, regex, email, salesforce, apex

I have to extract all the matching strings contained in a email.

The format is simple, 8 digits but when i test it it used to skip the last matching string.

A template email could be email: `Hi 12345678 87654321`

and it returns reference[] = ('12345678')

```
  public static String[] identificarsrNumber(Messaging.InboundEmail email){
    
    String[] reference= new List<String>();
    if (email.plainTextBody != null) {
        String[] splitemail = email.plainTextBody.split(' ');
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile('^\\d{8}$');
        for (String s : splitemail) {
            Matcher m = pt.matcher(s);
            if (m.find()) {
                reference.add(s);
            }
        }
     }
  return reference;
  }
```

Comment: `String[] reference= new List<String>();` <- Does that even compile? And if yes what List class are you using that can be both initiated and then assigned to String array? Because it wouldn't compile if the List class in question is `java.util.List`

Comment: Your code [works as expected](https://ideone.com/Q9AmSc) in Java after fixing a couple of typos.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS its apex, a transformer between java and sql, and yes it does compile.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry for the typos, the whole method was in spanish, and it doesn't work when you convert an input email to plainText

Comment: No idea what it is related to, maybe your data is not what you showed. If there can be Unicode spaces, try splitting with Unicode whitespace pattern, not just a regular ASCII space, try `email.plainTextBody.split("(?U)\\s+")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew may i split carriage return too?

Comment: `\s` matches any kind of whitespace. So, if you use `email.plainTextBody.split('(?U)\\s+');` does it work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks i will try it. Btw, what does '?U)\\s+' stand for?

Comment: Any Unicode whitespace, one or more repetitions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew omg it worked, yall were right i was adding the number + \s so i couldn't make the query after. Thanks!! Have a nice day :D (I will vote you answer if u post it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure you split your string with all Unicode whitespace chars:

```java
String[] splitemail = email.plainTextBody.split('(?U)\\s+');
```

In this case, `(?U)` stands for the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option that makes shorthand character classes Unicode-aware. So, `\s` starts matching all kinds of Unicode whitespace.

Comment: U got it! Thx Wiktor

Answer (score 0):

Does your email contains end of line or carriage return char ?
I guess that the last 8 digits part isn't matched because it is read as 87654321\n and you are searching for 8 digits only (by the use of ^ and $ around the digit matcher of your pattern)

Comment: it might be this, do i have to change my regex expresion then? or to remove \ns?

Comment: Just saw that Wiktor gave your a correct split pattern so I think you are ok now. Don't forget to accept his answer